# Azure Blob Download Timeouts - More than 2mb per minute?

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-blob-storage

So i have an application consuming a remote movie file held in Azure Blob Storage. The app is streaming the film, via ffmpeg, and processing each frame. So there is a computational overhead meaning that in some cases for a large film i think i'm being victim to the 2MB per minute limit that i see written about. My operation just randomly timeout with no error. If i run the same file locally then it works - so 99.9% sure it's a timeout issue.

Sometimes this processing can take several hours of constant downloading bit by bit

Is there any way to alter this timeout for Azure? I cannot find any method at the moment - i think it's hard coded?

thanks
Paul

Comment: how do you download it? please share the code.

Comment: Maybe you could try with [BlobRequestOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) set the ServerTimeout  and MaximumExecutionTime .

Comment: Is that you get timeout error when you download a large size file?